# VBA Last Row for Specific Text Value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub SeperateRowSub()

Dim FirstRowPFW As Integer
Dim LastRowPFW As Integer

FirstRowPFW = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Planning/Fieldwork", after:=Range("B6")).Row
LastRowPFW = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Planning/Fieldwork", after:=Range("B6"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

End Sub
```

FirstRowPFW returns the correct row that it starts at.
Lastrow continues to count the rest of the rows, even those outside of the "planning/fieldwork" criteria.

How can I fix the lastrowpfw variable to only count to the last row for cells containing "Planning/Fieldwork" ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what it is you're trying to do. Are you looking for the first row that says "Planning/Fieldwork", and then looking for the last row that says "Planning/Fieldwork" ?

Comment: Your code returns 10 and 18 respectively when I run it (which seems to be working as intended). http://i.imgur.com/HRasrds.png

Answer (score 3):

You code appears to function with correct data:

```
Sub SeperateRowSub()

    Dim FirstRowPFW As Integer
    Dim LastRowPFW As Integer

    FirstRowPFW = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Planning/Fieldwork", after:=Range("B6")).Row
    LastRowPFW = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Planning/Fieldwork", after:=Range("B6"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    MsgBox FirstRowPFW & vbCrLf & LastRowPFW
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was it was referencing a formula for Planning/Fieldwork, i.e. that text came up conditionally.  When I put a hardcoding statement in for that reference, it works.  Thank you for your help anyway!